# how can I pass 'scope' argument outside the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

how can I pass 'scope' argument outside the directive?
i need use it in some other component..

my code:

```
(function () {
angular.module('dmv.shared.components').
    directive('doImportPackage', ['Package', function (Package) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                onStart: '<',
                onFinish: '<',
                onError: '<'},
link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

  }
```

tnx !!

Comment: Directive Inherits the parent `$scope` automatically.

Comment: use `$scope.$parent` to access parent scope

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a controller. Since AngularJS works in 2-way data binding principle, these variables you assigned will already be updated from where you referenced, and you can use them with other directives too. For example, I assume that you use your directive as follows:

```
<do-import-package 
    on-start="myCtrl.onStart" 
    on-finish="myCtrl.onFinish" 
    on-error="myCtrl.onError">
</do-import-package>
```

You have following corresponding variables in myCtrl controllor:

```
this.onStart = some value;
this.onFinish = some value;
this.onErrod = some value;
```

Under normal conditions, you can bind other directive's attributes to these values and they will be updated in 2-way. For example, if you use the following directive, both directives should be updated with the same values.

```
<other-directive 
    on-start="myCtrl.onStart" 
    on-finish="myCtrl.onFinish" 
    on-error="myCtrl.onError">
</other-directive>
```

Comment: thank you! 
now I have a require to pass them to a component above.
is it possible ?

Comment: What's a component above? I'd like to help if you can give an example like the codes above.

Comment: i have 2 components, "tabsContainer" and "importTab".
as you explained, I can pass arguments  from the directive "importPackage" outside to "importTab" component.

now i need to pass them one step above to "tabsContainer"  (generally the tree of the app looks like this:  "tabsContainer" components calls "importTab" compenets that use "importPackage" directive).